# Execute npx webpack-dev-server, module not found

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

package.json

```
  {
  "name": "test5",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.1.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.0",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.1.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const {resolve} = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'built.js',
        path: resolve(__dirname, 'build')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            },
            {
                exclude: /\.(js|html|css)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/webpack.html'
        })
    ],
    mode: 'development',

    //devServer
    devServer: {
        contentBase: resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        compress: true,
        port: 3000,
        open: true
    }

};
```

Problem:

1. when I execute npx webpack-dev-server

2.ErrorMessage:

```
    Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-cli/bin/config/config-yargs'
    Require stack:
    - D:\webpack workspace\test5\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js

at Object.<anonymous> (D:\webpack workspace\test5\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js:65:1)

      code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
      requireStack: [
        'D:\\webpack workspace\\test5\\node_modules\\webpack-dev-server\\bin\\webpack-dev-server.js'
      ]
```

webpack-dev-server.js

```
// webpack-cli@3.3 path : 'webpack-cli/bin/config/config-yargs'
let configYargsPath;
try {
  require.resolve('webpack-cli/bin/config/config-yargs');
  configYargsPath = 'webpack-cli/bin/config/config-yargs';
} catch (e) {
  configYargsPath = 'webpack-cli/bin/config-yargs';
}
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-dynamic-require
require(configYargsPath)(yargs);

// It is important that this is done after the webpack yargs config,
// so it overrides webpack's version info.
yargs.version(getVersions());
yargs.options(options);

const argv = yargs.argv;
```

So, how to deal with this problem? I devoted lots of time to do this bug, but it didn't good.

(Also, these npm files on package.json are the latest.)

Please give me some efficient Tips. Thanks a lot

Solved:

```
        I have already solved this problem,
        we can use `webpack serve` to run `webpack-dev-server`
        so we just change the package.json file
    
        1."start-dev":"webpack-dev-server"
        to the
        "dev":"webpack serve"

     the final step is npm run dev;okay!successful!

2.First time we use npx webpack-dev-server
but now we just write npx webpack serve in terminal
okay!successful
```

Comment: I have already solved this problem,
we can use `webpack serve` to run `webpack-dev-server`
so we just change the package.json file
"start-dev":"webpack-dev-server"
to the
"dev":"webpack serve"